# A method to find two strings within distance

Tags: windows, search, string

I have a large text file collection.

I'm looking for a way to find two strings that are on the same line (in the same file) in the collection where the distance in characters between those two strings is not bigger than a distance that I specify.

For example, if a text file contains:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

and I pass the strings `fox` and `over` with a distance of 7 (or more) it will return this line because 7 is the distance between these words.

I'm running a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: If one string occurs at the end of a line and the second string occurs at the beginning of the next line, do you want to find that, too?

Comment: No I don't need those

Comment: This question really did not have to be put on hold. We disallow product recommendations in the sense of "What's the best tool to do *XYZ*?" if no research effort whatsoever is shown and if it's obvious that everyone would chime in with their own opinion because there are dozens of possible answers. If all that needs to be done is to reword a question from "I'm looking for a tool to…" to "How do I …?", then closing it seems a little too hard. At least an effort could be made into rewriting the question before voting to close it. (cc @scott)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use egrep.  Or grep -e option.

> `egrep -o "fox.{1,7}over" filename.txt`

In general it is :

> `egrep -o "string1.{1,7}string2" filename.txt`

All the above options will return only the matched portion. For the full line to be returned, do not use the -o option. So it would be:

> `egrep "string1.{1,7}string2" filename.txt`

To apply it to all files in a folder you would use:

> `egrep "string1.{1,7}string2" *`

All these assume that there is at least one character separation.

Comment: Eventually I used Windows Grep, but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on Windows, use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) together with its plugin [RegEx Helper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppregexhelper/)

> A Notepad++ plugin that allows users to develop regular expressions and test them against their open documents.

[image]

If you want the whole line, use `^.*fox.{0,7}over.*$`  instead of `fox.{0,7}over`